# On keyup or click get this element

Tags: jquery, click, keyup

I want to know which element has been clicked or keyuped. Something like the below:

```
$('button, input').on('click keyup', function() {

    var self = $(this);

    if (self == button)
        ...
    else if (self == input)
        ...

};
```

I can't do `self.attr('name') == 'something'` because the button has no name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($(this).is('button')) {
} else if ($(this).is('input')) {
}
```

What malificent meant was

```
if ($(this).prop('tagName')=='BUTTON'){
} else if ($(this).prop('tagName')=='INPUT') {
}
```

though I would use a switch because it's tidier

```
switch ($(this).prop('tagName')){
    case 'BUTTON':
        //do stuff
    break;
    case 'INPUT':
        //do stuff
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to distinguish if it's an input or button tag you can use

```
$(this).prop("tagName")
```